# How to insert element in array

Tags: list, prolog

I have this task for my next laboratory:

"Write a predicate to add value 1 after every even element from a list."

I think that I need to recursive functions. This is what i was thinking about

```
addE([],_,[_]).
addE([H|T], _,[H|TR]):-addE(T,_,TR).

addOneEven([],[]).
addOneEven([H|T],[H|TR]):-
    H mod 2 =:= 0, addE([H|H], 1, [H|TR]),
    addOneEven(T,TR).
```

It keeps returning me false.

I would like to specify that I am a newbie in prolog language.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write:

```
addOneEven([],[]).
addOneEven([H|T],[H|T1]):-
     H mod 2 =:= 1,
     addOneEven(T,T1).
 addOneEven([H|T],[H1|TR]):- 
     H mod 2 =:= 0,H1 is H+1,
     addOneEven(T,TR).
```

Your addE predicate wasn't very useful since it only traversed the list without adding anything to any element, also another problem was that you must have a clause for the case that H mod 2 =:=1.